# NextRouter was not mounted

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, frontend, url-routing

I am trying to implement a search feature for my property renting app. I added the Nextjs Router. When I go to localhost:3000/search, however, I get this error:

```
Server Error
Error: Error: NextRouter was not mounted. https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
useRouter
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/next/dist/client/router.js (122:15)
pages\search.tsx (10:28) @ Search

   8 | const Search = () => {
   9 | const [searchFilters, setSearchFilters] = useState(false);
> 10 | const router = useRouter();
     |                        ^
  11 | 
  12 | return (
  13 |     <Box>
Call Stack
renderWithHooks
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5731:15)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderNode
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6259:12)
renderHostElement
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5642:3)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/doguk/Desktop/emlakuygulamasi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5952:5)
```

My code in `search.tsx` is as follows, it is not as of yet complete:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Image from 'next/image';
import {Flex, Box, Text, Icon} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BsFilter } from 'react-icons/bs';
import SearchFilters from '../components/SearchFilters';

const Search = () => {
    const [searchFilters, setSearchFilters] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <Box>
            <Flex
            cursor="pointer"
            bg="gray.100"
            borderBottom="1px"
            borderColor="gray.200"
            p="2"
            fontWeight="black"
            fontSize="lg"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
            onClick={() => setSearchFilters((prevFilters) => !prevFilters)}
            >
        <Text>Filtrele</Text>
        <Icon paddingLeft="2" w="7" as={BsFilter}></Icon>
            </Flex>
            {searchFilters && <SearchFilters />}
        </Box>
    ) 
}

export default Search;
```

I read the Nextjs docs, and I've checked Stackoverflow for answers but none works. This should be fairly straightforward but I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using Next.js version 13, and the `app` directory?

Comment: I am using   Nextjs version 13.0.6, I checked the package-lock.json file and also used npx next --version to find this out. For directory, it's: myproject/pages/search.tsx along with app and index tsx files.

Comment: Okay, where are you using this `Search` component?

Comment: What do you mean where exactly? This isn't a component, search.tsx is a page. When I go to that page (localhost:3000/search) I get the router error. For components I have the search filter component in components file that I have not implemented into search.tsx page fully as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

try doing `import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";`

Earlier `useRouter from "next/router"` was used but after the introduction of [NEXT-13](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4).
The package was changed from "next/router" to "next/navigation".

Migrating from the pages directory:

- The new useRouter hook should be imported from next/navigation and
  not next/router.

here's the reference - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).